# How to swap two columns in R based on a specific condition?

Tags: r, function, if-statement, conditional-statements, swap

I have two columns,say, a & b, and I have to swap the values of a & b if the value in column b is greater than the value in column a.

I've written a function to swap the variable if the condition is met

```
a     b
110   70
120   80 
80    110
```

```
swap_if<- function (a, b,missing=NA) 
{
  if(b>a)
  {
    a = a + b
    b = a - b
    a = a - b
  }
}  


swap_if(a,b)
```

The output should come as :

```
a     b
110   70
120   80 
110   80
```

But I'm getting an error

```
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: Have you tried `ifelse`?

Comment: I tried but I'm not sure how will we use ifelse here, when there are multiple statements to execute swap the values? (new to the language)

Comment: @hmhensen `ifelse` only returns one value for each branch, the question needs two values returned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's only 2 columns, `pmin` and `pmax` are your friends here.

```
temp_min = pmin(df$a, df$b)
df$a = pmax(df$a, df$b)
df$b = temp_min
```

If it's more than 2 columns, than the apply sort scales better.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your input is given as

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(110,120,80), b = c(70,80,110))
```

Then the following can give the expected output:

```
df_swap <- as.data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, function(v) sort(v,decreasing = T))))
colnames(df_swap) <- names(df)
```

such that

```
> df_swap
   a b
1 110 70
2 120 80
3 110 80
```

Answer (score 2):

Gregor's solution is the best, but thought I'd add an extra.

```
swap_if <- function (a, b, missing = NA) {
  c <- a
  x <- ifelse(b > a, b, a)
  y <- ifelse(b <= a, b, c)
  z <- data.frame(x, y)
  return(z) }

swap_if(a, b)
    x  y
1 110 70
2 120 80
3 110 80
```